Reverse diode across power supply output terminals


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Hello,
Could someone please explain the role of the D1 diode in this circuit? This is part of the power supply filtering in a VHF receiver.
This could be related to this similar thread
What's the purpose of a diode across capacitor after voltage regulator?.
However, that one is talking about a split power supply with a virtual ground.

With the schematics of the circuit, the diode is used as a simple reverse polarity protection, and also from short negative spikes that may appear on the 12V input in an automotive environment.

Here is the full schematics
https://www.thanksbuyer.com/download/50688-Airband-English-version.pdf
It is one of the Aviation Band Receiver kits from China.

It blows the fuse if you connect the 12 V with the wrong polarity. It also "shorts out" negative-going noise spikes that might appear on the automotive power bus.
